# How to get list of data from a file using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm working on this simple My task is to add a new REST api
I went ahead and created a new controller where I'm able to retrieve all of the data from sql file. However I'm stuck on getting the list of hotels.Thanks.

Here's my code:

CONTROLLER:

```
package sample.data.jpa.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import sample.data.jpa.domain.City;
import sample.data.jpa.domain.Hotel;
import sample.data.jpa.domain.HotelSummary;
import sample.data.jpa.domain.Review;
import sample.data.jpa.service.CityService;
import sample.data.jpa.service.CityRepository;
import sample.data.jpa.service.HotelService;

@Controller
class HotelController {

@Autowired(required = true)
private CityRepository cityRepository;

@Autowired(required = true)
private CityService cityService;

private HotelService hotelService;

private City cityObject;
private Hotel hotelObject;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllData")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Iterable<City> getAllData() {
    return this.cityRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Iterable<Hotel> getBestHotelsWithBestRatings() {
    return this.hotelService.getHotel(cityObject, name);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest to forget pulling full data set from DB and filtering it in applications server. It may add huge overhead. Remember, talking to DB is expensive and you should optimize for reading as small data set as possible.

You should filter that in DB query. Therefore I recommend looking at spring-data-jpa [`@Query` usage](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Your repository may look something like this:

```
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, Long> {

  @Query("select * from Hotel h where h.averageRating > ?1")
  List<Hotel> findAllPopular(int averageRating);
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm with you on that one which is why I added a new dependency to my pom.xml like this:

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: But my question is still pending :(

Comment: Sorry, I am not following these comments

Comment: BTW, I updated my code sample to match the question. I screwed which DB table before.